# Mathjax Display Issues (Breaking Formatting In Certain Places Only)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, mathjax

I'm displaying some mathjax and it works generally fine. E.g. within a DIV. However, when I insert it into a Bootstrap Accordion it breaks the formatting of said accordion but only in the title Mathjax seems to insert its own spans that inherit things like padding and margin which I think is causing this.

See below code, its also on this page www.clevertree.co.uk if you click on one of the learn more links on the 9 images halfway down the page. The first bit below breaks and the second bit is fine.

```
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="panel-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_core1" href="#core1content2">
                                <span>Coordinate Geometry in the (??x,y??) Plane</span>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->

                    <div id="core1content2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="circled">
                                <li>Equation of a straight line, including the forms ??y-y_{1}=m(x-x_{1})?? and ??ax + by + c = 0??</li>
                                <li>Conditions for two straight lines to be parallel or perpendicular to each other</li>
                            </ul><!-- /.circled -->
                        </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div><!-- /.content -->

                </div><!-- /.panel -->
```

Comment: So, play around with the DOM and CSS inspectors a bit to see which style rule(s) are at fault.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to make MathJax ignore the styling from certain elements it is inheriting? Like don't inherit padding, margin or colour?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with Boostrap using `display:none` on its hidden content. Since this means browsers won't lay out the content, this prevents MathJax from measuring widths and heights correctly. [See this blog post for more details.](http://boolesrings.org/krautzberger/2014/07/12/mathjax-best-practices-avoid-displaynone/)

Long story short, to be safe, you need to trigger a re-render of the content in the accordion.

I'm not too familiar with boostrap but combining [boostrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) with [MathJax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html0) something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pwLxymq/3/) might be a start.

Alternatively, you could configure the MathJax preprocessors (e.g., [the TeX one](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html)) to ignore the accordion and then replace `Rerender` with `Typeset` (this saves one round of typesetting of that content but the second pass will be much quicker so it will depend if that's worth it).

EDIT E.g., for your site modify your configuration to

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
            tex2jax:{
                inlineMath: [['%%%%','%%%%'], ['??','??']],
                displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['@@', '@@']],
                ignoreClass: "panel"
            }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip - I think I was a bit unclear in my description though, the content in the accordion works but in the accordion title does not. In the jsFiddle if I put stuff into the title (e.g. instead of Collapsible Group Item #1) it works, but in my one, using the same code, it does not work and the layout is still messed up. Even using this for all elements, can you give me a guide on how to configure the MathJax processor to ignore the Accordion? I already have a bit of config code for the Mathjax at the top of the page? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a live sample? Also, which input are you using?

Comment: Hi Thanks Peter. Yes I do. www.clevertree.co.uk. There is a modal towards the bottom that is called Core 1. If you click on the Learn More button you can see some Mathjax in the 2nd Accordion title (it should read Coordinate Geometry in the (x,y) Plane). Thanks ever so much for your help.

Comment: Hm. Not sure what's going on. I'll have to look into it later. I added a configuration example.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That config example worked in that the formatting is not messed up now, but the Mathjax has not been rendered at all in the panel items. Do I need to do something more to ignore the panel class inheritance but still render the actual maths content? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Peter again. Any more ideas please?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time all week. Have you tried isolating the problem to a more minimal case?

Comment: How do you mean Peter? I can't seem to really do anything to fix it.